# How to display page loading GIF on page with <frameset>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

In this case i have two HTML page (just let say two)
named *index.html* and *list.html*

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frame</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="20%,80%" bordercolor='blue' noresize id="judul">
    <frame src="Judul.html" id="atas">
    <frameset cols="15%,85%" id="kolom">
        <frame src="list.html" id="daftar">
        <frame src="new 2.html" id="tengah">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

**list.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="welcome.html" target="tengah" style="color:blue;margin-left:40px;font-family:Segoe UI;">Main page</a>
    <a href="list.html" target="tengah" style="color:blue;margin-left:40px;font-family:Segoe UI;">About Us</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So what i want is when the link from **list.html** call the page the targetted frame will show a loading GIF and then hide it when the load complete.

And the question is what code should i put there ? and where should i put it ?

and please make it as detail as possible,since i'm very new to HTML and it's stuff

and thanks for all suggestion

Comment: Ok, we want to see your effort in making that effect. But before anything else, framesets are obsolete. You should avoid them. Think JS appending and removing an `<img>` on the page instead.

Comment: You don't really see enough of the great frames from the nineties anymore, good for you going old school and all, a sad day for your future users though.

Comment: Use AJAX instead of frames.

Comment: Well that's the best i can do now,sorry but i've never touch HTML before

Comment: Get a book on modern web design. Repeating the mistakes designers made 15 years ago when they didn't have better alternatives is not a great way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is still CSS or Jquery since framesets are deprecated anyway...

Example CSS, using the :hover modifier (assuming you have onhover trigger function):

```
.myloading_gif {
    display: none:
}

.myloading_gif:hover {
    display: block:
}
```

If its a click element you cannot solve it with CSS, then you should consider JQuery:

```
$("#myHrefID").click(function() {
    $("#myLoadingIcon").toggle();
});
```

And when the loading is finished just call "toggle" again.

```
$("#myLoadingIcon").toggle();
```

There are many ways to achieve this. My examples just should be just a little help since I am not 100% sure that I got your point.

Comment: hi @steini anyways which, could you please provide a demo (jsfiddle or plunkr) of your solution, which you think working for you?